# Scalar properties not working except in source repository

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I created the NSManagedObjects, I used Scalar properties. Such as:

```
@objc(Candy)
class Candy: DefaultDeserializableManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: Int
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var smallImageUrl: String
    @NSManaged var largeImageUrl: String
    @NSManaged var price: Int
    @NSManaged var sortOrder: Int
}
```

I did this because I didn't want to have to walk a second link to get usable primitives (ex. `self.sortOrder.intValue`). Everything worked great, and I am even able to use SwiftyJSON and `setValue:forKey:` to deserialize, which has been really nice.

Unfortunately, things are only working on the source repository. I didn't catch this until helping someone else get set up. Even if I re-clone on the same machine as the working repository, and try to set it up, things aren't working. When trying to get the values of the primitives, I get:

> 2015-01-21 10:45:48.372 [5355:178924] CoreData: error: Property 'id' is a scalar type on class 'Candy' that does not match its Entity's property's scalar type.  Dynamically generated accessors do not support implicit type coercion.  Cannot generate a getter method for it.
>
> 2015-01-21 10:45:48.373 [5355:178924] -[Candy id]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79ea3df0

My `.gitignore` is as follows, I don't believe there's anything core-data specific that would be ignored in this case:

```
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate
```

I have tried resetting my Simulator for the working repository, and reinstalling, and it still works. Same for cleaning before building.

Comment: I've never managed to get scalar types working with swift NSManagedObjects at all, let alone once mysteriously. I'll be interested to see an answer for this

Comment: I haven't understood why your problem is related to cloning the repository, but the scalar properties should have a type Int16, Int32 or Int64, depending on how you defined the Core Data attribute (Integer 16/32/64).

Comment: My reason for mentioning the cloning (and my `.gitignore`) is that I am wondering if there is some type of user pref -- or something that's not in version control -- that is directing Core Data to look for scalars and not objects. I know it seems asinine, but it's literally the only thing that would be different.

Comment: @cscott530: As far as I know, this decision is only made at runtime, from the type of the actual properties. So you can for example change `price: Int32` to `price: NSNumber` in the managed object subclass without editing the Core Data model. But as I said, `Int` is wrong because it would be 32-bit or 64-bit depending on the platform.

Answer (score 2):

It will work on devices that are 64 bit, and won't work on devices that are 32 bit.

We just had this issue, and in the CoreData model the attribute was set to Int64. In Swift, when you have:

```
@NSManaged var id: Int
```

It tries to auto convert the scalar. It works on 64 bit devices as it is converting the Int64 to Int (which is 64bit). It fails on 32 bit devices as it cannot convert the Int64 to Int (which is 32bit).

Either change the Int to Int64, or change it to NSNumber.